# What does the phrase "play a bluff" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms, phrases, idioms-in-context

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "play a bluff" in the following sentence from the description of the game Golazo:

> You can **play a bluff** to deceive your opponent and show off your
> skills at one-touch football to keep possession.

I know the lexical meaning of the word "bluff", but I am wondering if it has a soccer-specific meaning that I may not be aware of. For example, the words like "tackle", "slide tackle" etc. have well-defined meanings in soccer.

Answer (score 2):

In football, (ie association football, or soccer, but also other codes) you don't tend to talk about bluffing.  The word used is "dummy". Other words are "feint", or "feigning (a pass/shot)". The most common dummy is when a player pretends to play the ball but allows it to go past them and on to a teammate. There are specific moves, such as "Pele runaround" or "Cruyff turn".

The writing looks like it has been written by someone with no knowledge of football.